# A random-string function produces many duplicates

Tags: php, windows, random, duplicates

I am using the function below to generate random strings for filenames. I got no problems on Unix machines but I have many duplicates on Windows. I just made a test and generated 100.000 strings with the result, that each string occurs 227 (??) times. Could anyone explain this? Even with `rand()` I got duplicates, but `srand()` seems to work.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 6)
{
        $rows = array();
        array_push($rows, range('A', 'Z'));
        array_push($rows, range('a', 'z'));
        array_push($rows, range(0, 9));

        $signs = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $signs = array_merge($signs, $row);
        }
        shuffle($signs);
        shuffle($signs);

        $password = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $password .= $signs[array_rand($signs, 1)];
        }
        return $password;
    }
```

Comment: Apart from what I've already mentioned in my answer, please add information about the environment where you're getting this behaviour - windows version, web server version, PHP version...

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, Windows file names aren't case sensitive, so you should only use either lowercase or uppercase characters in your source arrays, not both.

The rest is basically upto the actual implementation of the PHP processor you're using, rather than Windows vs. *nix. Perhaps they rely on timer resolution and keep no internal state - that would be bad given that usually the timer resolution is about 15ms, which isn't a whole lot. In any case, it's most likely an issue with the PHP implementation, not Windows itself, as this code in C# nicely illustrates:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

byte[] buf = new byte[10 * 100000];

rnd.NextBytes(buf);

buf
   .Select((val, idx) => new { Index = idx, Value = val })
   .ToLookup(i => i.Index / 10)
   .Select(i => string.Join(string.Empty, 
                            i.Select(j => j.Value.ToString("X2")).ToArray()))
   .GroupBy(i => i)
   .Where(i => i.Count() > 1)
   .Dump();
```

This creates 100 000 random strings of 20 characters (`0` to `F`) and looks for duplicates. In a few hundred tests, I haven't had a single collision. So if you've got trouble with the random generator in PHP, go look at the particular implementation of PHP you're using, rather than blaming Windows :)

It's interesting how your code does a few passes of the randomness (shuffling the `$signs` array twice and then picking randomly from that?). Doing this most likely *reduces* the randomness of the data rather than increasing it. Seems just like a stupid attempt at hiding the password generation mechanism behind layers of obscurity (and then open sourcing it... eh :D).

As for passwords (your code seems to indicate that's what it was used for), you should probably use the crypto-secure randoms anyway - they're far less predictable, more random and less prone to bias.